# JSF Initialization Error only during first Login after Reboot of Server

Tags: jsf-2.2, mojarra

I am experiencing what seems to be a JSF initialization error after the first login request after rebooting the server.  If I refresh the request and resubmit the login, everything works but the first login request always returns this:

```
    [2016-07-27T23:02:40.089-0400] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=34 _ThreadName=Thread-8] [timeMillis: 1469674960089] [levelValue: 800] [[
  2016-07-27 23:02:40.89->[DEBUG]->com.ge.de.cov.reports.beans.LoginBean->Line 127->login()->Invoking login!]]

[2016-07-27T23:02:40.378-0400] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=34 _ThreadName=Thread-8] [timeMillis: 1469674960378] [levelValue: 800] [[
  2016-07-27 23:02:40.377->[DEBUG]->com.ge.de.cov.reports.beans.LoginBean->Line 162->login()->Done! page=</pages/main.xhtml>]]

[2016-07-27T23:02:40.398-0400] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [javax.faces] [tid: _ThreadID=34 _ThreadName=http-listener-2(5)] [timeMillis: 1469674960398] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Unable to obtain InjectionProvider from init time FacesContext. Does this container implement the Mojarra Injection SPI?]]

[2016-07-27T23:02:40.399-0400] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [javax.faces] [tid: _ThreadID=34 _ThreadName=http-listener-2(5)] [timeMillis: 1469674960399] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.view.facelets.TagHandlerDelegateFactory. Attempting to find backup.]]

[2016-07-27T23:02:40.402-0400] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=34 _ThreadName=http-listener-2(5)] [timeMillis: 1469674960402] [levelValue: 900] [[
  StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.view.facelets.TagHandlerDelegateFactory.
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.AbstractTagLibrary$UserComponentHandlerFactory.createHandler(AbstractTagLibrary.java:344)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.AbstractTagLibrary.createTagHandler(AbstractTagLibrary.java:723)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.CompositeTagLibrary.createTagHandler(CompositeTagLibrary.java:194)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TagUnit.createFaceletHandler(TagUnit.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextUnit.createFaceletHandler(TextUnit.java:117)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.CompilationUnit.getNextFaceletHandler(CompilationUnit.java:115)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceUnit.createFaceletHandler(NamespaceUnit.java:82)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.CompilationUnit.getNextFaceletHandler(CompilationUnit.java:115)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.CompilationUnit.createFaceletHandler(CompilationUnit.java:106)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.CompilationManager.createFaceletHandler(CompilationManager.java:381)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doCompile(SAXCompiler.java:468)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doCompile(SAXCompiler.java:430)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:124)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.createFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:481)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.access$100(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:106)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:199)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:197)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache$1.newInstance(DefaultFaceletCache.java:86)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache$1.newInstance(DefaultFaceletCache.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.util.ExpiringConcurrentCache$1.call(ExpiringConcurrentCache.java:99)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at com.sun.faces.util.ExpiringConcurrentCache.get(ExpiringConcurrentCache.java:114)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletCache.java:124)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletCache.java:63)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:295)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:239)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:988)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:99)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at com.ge.de.cov.reports.filters.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:41)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]]

[2016-07-27T23:02:40.408-0400] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [javax.faces] [tid: _ThreadID=34 _ThreadName=http-listener-2(5)] [timeMillis: 1469674960408] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.render.RenderKitFactory. Attempting to find backup.]]
```

Comment: Looks like classpath pollution with multiple different versioned libraries or a dirty server work folder.

Comment: Hi BalusC - I have also upgraded to GF 4.1.1 to start clean and made sure that there was only the javax.faces.jar file in modules directory for it and that I am not including any JSF jar files in my WEB-INF/lib directory, but I still get the same error after start up.  BTW - I am using delegate=false because I have a different version of mail.jar file in my WEB-INF/lib directory.

Comment: I was up until 4:30 am this morning trying this and that and nothing I have tried seems to resolve the issue. I even went through all JAR files in GF and extracted their classes to see which include TagHandlerDelegateFactory class, and the only places I found that class are the javax.faces.jar file and a bundle#.jar file in osgi-cache.

Comment: Just FYI - for now I just added a redirect.jsp page for error 500 in the web.xml so that users can be redirected to the context URL when this initialization error occurs after startup, as the server gets rebooted daily at midnight.  BTW - I am starting to consider using a different container instead of GF.  I've been spending too many sleep-less nights recently trying to figure out GF class loading issues and other GF issues.  Which server and JSF implementation do you use?